# Gihub repo owner (Yii2-user) left repository - How to proceed?

Tags: php, github, yii2

[Yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user) is a very popular Yii2 extension for user management. There are lots of forks and contributors. Many issues and PRs are awaiting for being integrated or at least answered.

But there is no activity from the repo owner since over 3 months which is very untypical for him compared to his activity before.

Currently I am sitting on a fork and maintaining my branches. This works for a short time but I do not get PRs from the others and cannot sync with the original repo anymore.

What is a common practice to make a repo survive if the owner abandons its repo (and cannot be reached)? How to proceed as a single fork owner and as community of all fork owners?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author? I have seen some projects with a sentence like "This lib is outdated. Go to repo foo maintained by bar, for a continued version". If you can think you can handle the maintenance, you could ask about a link to your repo.

Comment: Getting a link to the new repo is one thing. But what to do with existing PRs and open Issues? Does everybody have to recreate the PRs? And how to send a PR to a repo which you didn't make a fork of? Does Github offer tasks for such a case?

Comment: Maybe, but - as Eric S. Raymond in his epic work [The Cathedral and the Bazaar](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/homesteading/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s02.html) in rule no 5 says: _When you lose interest in a program, your last duty to it is to hand it off to a competent successor._ - he should find a successor to continue the success of his code.

Answer (score 1):

## Repos should be handed-off before being abandoned.

The whole point of git and github, is maintaining a chain of authority and revision. If a repo is abandoned, no-one can access it, take it over, or pass it along, except the owner. If this isn't possible, then you'll have to make your current fork a new master, and try to re-organize communities of other forks, to hopefully source yours as the new main branch. Good luck with that.